# a question on the cube of gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

This is an old question. In that answer,how can we get $\gcd(j^3, k^3)=1?$ What formula did he use?
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmx4N.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the solution linked to, we have $\gcd(j,k)=1$. We want to conclude from this that $\gcd(j^3,k^3)=1$.

Suppose to the contrary that $\gcd(j^3,k^3)=d\gt 1$. Then some prime $p$ divides $d$.

So $p$ divides $j^3$, and therefore $p$ divides $j$. Similarly, $p$ divides $k$. So $p$ divides both $j$ and $k$, contradicting the fact that $\gcd(j,k)=1$.

Comment: how can you get p divides j from p divides cube of j?

Comment: Euclid's Lemma: If a prime $p$ divides a product $x\cdot y$, then it divides $x$ or $y$ (or both). Because $p$ divides $j^3$, it divides $j\cdot j^2$,  so it divides $j$ (and we are finished) or it divides $j^2$. If it divides $j^2$, it divides $j\cdot j$, so it divides $j$ (or $j$!).

Comment: ^ Solid answer. More simply: if j and k are relatively prime, so must j^3 and k^3.

Comment: @GrantStenger: I agree, if one makes a comment about unique factorization. Here is a cute, perhaps excessively cute, alternative proof. Since $\gcd(j,k)=1$, there are integers $s$ and $t$ such that $js+rk=1$. Take the fifth power of both sides, and expand the left-hand side. We get that $1$ is a linear combination of $j^3$ and $k^3$.